# Ruby on Rails Partial Templates Understanding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, renderpartial, partials

I have a short question to help me understand Rails partials. I am new to RoR and just working through Agile Web Development with Rails. I am in Iteration F1 if you have the same book.

When i am not using partials, the show.html.erb from the carts looks like this:

```
<% if notice %>
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<% end %>

<!-- START_HIGHLIGHT -->
<h2>Your Cart</h2>
<table>
<!-- END_HIGHLIGHT -->
  <% @cart.line_items.each do |item| %>
<!-- START_HIGHLIGHT -->
    <tr>
      <td><%= item.quantity %>&times;</td>
      <td><%= item.product.title %></td>
      <td class="item_price"><%= number_to_currency(item.total_price) %></td>
    </tr>
<!-- END_HIGHLIGHT -->
  <% end %>
<!-- START_HIGHLIGHT -->
  <tr class="total_line">
    <td colspan="2">Total</td>
    <td class="total_cell"><%= number_to_currency(@cart.total_price) %></td>
  </tr>
<!-- END_HIGHLIGHT -->
<!-- START_HIGHLIGHT -->
</table>
<!-- END_HIGHLIGHT -->

<%= button_to 'Empty cart', @cart, method: :delete,
    data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

Then, when I start to use partials, I created a class called _cart.html.erb and put this in it:

```
<h2>Your Cart</h2>
<table>
  <%= render(cart.line_items) %>

  <tr class="total_line">
    <td colspan="2">Total</td>
    <td class="total_cell"><%= number_to_currency(cart.total_price) %></td>
  </tr>

</table>

<%= button_to 'Empty cart', cart, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

And modified my show.html.erb to this:

```
<% if notice %>
    <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<% end %>

  <%= render(@cart) %>
```

So, my confusion is now, why do I have to use @cart.something when I dont have partials. For my understanding it was the model I was using which called carts.rb. So, when I then create a partial, then I just simply use cart instead of @cart and the partial is still using the model?

But why then I use render(@cart)? Is this command then just using my partial _cart.html.erb? 
can anybody help me to complete my understanding of it? probably it is like it is, but i confuses me a little bit at the moment :)

Comment: You sound really very confused. _cart.html.erb isn't a class, it's a partial btw. "@cart" is set in your controller, something like "@cart = Cart.find params[:id]". This is separate to your model.

Comment: :D yes.. you are right.. i really dont know why i made this mistake.. 

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say `render(@cart)`, what's really happening behind the scenes is Rails is making a lot of assumptions for you based on the *conventions* of how Rails generally works.

Let's start off with the `@cart` variable. This is an *instance* variable, which is a variable that's accessible to anything inside your controller. Views have a special relationship with controllers, so instance variables defined within a controller method are available within the view.

You **could** use `@cart` within your partial, and everything would work fine in this case. But it's generally a bad idea - you want partials to be reusable in different spots, and assuming that an instance variable exists introduces *coupling* between your controller and the partial.

The solution that Rails provides is the ability to pass local variables to  a partial. Remember how I said that `render(@cart)` is a shortcut? What's really happening behind the scenes is this:

```
render partial: 'carts/cart', locals: { cart: @cart }
```

Because you're following Rails conventions, Rails can make the following assumptions:

- The  partial for a `Cart` is located in `app/views/carts/_cart.html.erb`
- That partial is going to use a local variable named `cart`, which is passed to the method.

So as a result, the following:

```
render @cart
```

has the same effect as the more verbose line above.

Comment: Hi Ryan, thank you very much. 

I dont know why i forgot about the @variable, because i put a lot of them, i think it was just the usage of the partials :)

thank you very much for your explanation. this helps me a lot. 

have a nice day